# Bootstrap menu in wordpress wont open on some pages

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, menu, navigation

On some pages of my wordpress website the bootstrap dropdown wont open. 
If you check out some of the pages you will see that on some pages the dropdown probably wont open but on some other pages it does.

I used the wp bootstrap navwalker.

All help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see your console you'll see an error saying "$ is undefined." The reason for this is that JQuery is loaded after your bootstrap.js.

If your refresh the page few times the dropdown menu works. See the image below.

[Working Menu](http://postimg.org/image/qewlgjqgv/)

Try and change the order in which you load JQuery and this should solve the problem.